# Suddenly sudo gets error 'usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0

Tags: sudo, root

Yesterday I was using my computer normally, but, today, when I turned it on, this problem suddenly appears.

I understand that there's quite a few things to do to try to fix this issue.

When I run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

`sudo` gets an error:

```
/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

My question isn't about how to fix this, **but how and why this happened**?

Comment: You ran `sudo chown something-or-the-other`

Comment: Or just something like "sudo nautilus" and something slipped. Obs.: Never do that! Use `sudo -H nautilus` if you must open it with root permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible that you ran a recursive `chmod` command at the root level recently?  Accidentally or otherwise?  Resetting chmod to a standard value like 0755 will remove all setuid bits.

There are dozens of files on your filesystem that require special permissions to work correctly and for which a simple permission like 0755 or even 0777 won't work.

There isn't a reliable way to undo this without reinstalling, since this is a lossy operation: there's no way to revert each file to the permissions it was previously.

Comment: Perfect. I did ran chmod at root level yesterday. Now I understand (:

Comment: @MatheusCirillo how did you fixed your issue I am having the same issue now. can you please write the answer.

Comment: @thomasrutter I am working on `windows Cygwin`,with AWS `ubuntu`  in my case do I need to reinstall the Cygwin or create a new instance for ubuntu.?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Unfortunately I had to reinstall ubuntu. In your case, you'll probably have to create a new instance, since there isn't a reliable way to undo this.

Answer (score -1):

Its because of Permission issue.

```
 $ su
 Password: <type your user password>
```

Switch to root user and run the command

```
# pkexec chmod a=rx,u+ws /usr/bin/sudo
```

Then check it by typing from the user

```
$sudo -l
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: There is no root password by default on Ubuntu... Of course you can set one, but it is not recommended and not that many people do it.

Comment: are you mad ?  i say type your root password not type root as password...

Comment: No I am not. User `root` has no password on Ubuntu (`/etc/shadow` contains: `root:!:17264:0:99999:7:::`). You can't `su` to `root` like on other Unixen. You can only `sudo`.

Comment: okay i'll change it

Comment: sorry for the misbehave

Comment: @KevalMangukiya Still not OK, `su` needs the target user password. You can use another means to get a root prompt in Ubuntu. In this case, the rescue prompt would be likely the right one.

Comment: works for me, thanks !